# unable to remove 2nd instance of a value within a string

Tags: php

i know that the `str_replace( )`  will remove an instance of a string.

but how do i remove just one instance of a string within a string.

below is the example of a URL address, i only want to remove the first instance of the  exampleDirecotry/`

```
www.example/exampleDirectory/exampleDirectory/index.php
```

i need to first test that there are two instance of exampleDirectory/ and if so, remove one of them.

```
$url  = www.example/exampleDirectory/exampleDirectory/index.php 

if ($url ==  ) 
{
  $newURL  = str_replace($url, "", "exampleDirectory/");

}
```

Comment: You should have a look at `substr_replace()`, first you must find the offset and length of the string you would like to replace.

Comment: hi everyone. i only want to remove the first instance of exampleDirecotory/.

Comment: `$newURL  = str_replace("e/exampleDirectory/", "e", $url);`  would be an option ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by finding the offset and length of the first substring. To check so there are more than one instance you could use `substr_count()`:

```
$search = "exampleDirectory/";
// check so the string exists more than once
if (substr_count($url, $search) > 1) {
  $length = strlen($search);
  $offset = strpos($url, $search);
  // replace the first occurance of the string
  $newURL = substr_replace($url, "", $offset, $length);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have made very simple error, Paul. I do it from time to time as well.
The proper sequence of parameters is:

```
str_replace($search, $replace, $subject)
```

The easiest way:

```
$newURL = str_replace("/exampleDirectory/exampleDirectory", 
                      "/exampleDirectory", $url);
```